# Read headers HappyX

Tags: web, nim-lang

I was intrigued to try this new framework for building APIs, but I don't understand where to find the inHeaders. In fact I had this problem also with the cookies, but then I used inCookies (had to find it myself even tho it was logical, having it in the documentation could help), but the same logic seems not to exist for outHeaders.

Comment: Nvm I found out that req has everything I need. Anyways I have another question, how can I redirect from a route to another one?

Comment: Open another post for your other question. You may self-answer this post if you think this can be useful to others. Do not use abbreviations in your posts or your comments.